# extracting data from multidimensional array via PHP and store in text file

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, foreach

I would like to extract data from the following JSON arrays, to a variable that i would like to use to create a text file

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 123:         
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => TICKET
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => ------------------------------------------------
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => user 1         
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => info x        
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => ------------------------------------------------
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => TEXT 1
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => TEXT 2
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => TEXT 4
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => TEXT 4
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => TEXT 5
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => TEXT 6                       
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => TEXT 7
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => TEXT 8 
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => TEXT 9
        )


)
```

I use the following PHP, but only the array 15 value is returned in my text file.

```
$ticket = file_get_contents('php://input');
$ticket_output = json_decode($ticket,true);

$ticket_output_def = $ticket_output['ticket']; 

$ticket_output_txt = print_r($ticket_output_def,true); 

foreach ($ticket_output_def as $array){ 

$array0 = $array[0];
$array1 = $array[1];

$text = $array0 . $array1;


}

$filename = "output.txt";

file_put_contents($filename, $text);
```

Comment: `$text .= $array0 . $array1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's normal since you reset $text at every loop iteration!

Maybe try this :

```
$ticket = file_get_contents('php://input');
$ticket_output = json_decode($ticket,true);

$ticket_output_def = $ticket_output['ticket']; 

$ticket_output_txt = print_r($ticket_output_def,true); 
$text = "";
foreach ($ticket_output_def as $array){ 

    $array0 = $array[0];
    $array1 = $array[1];

    $text .= $array0 . $array1;


}

$filename = "output.txt";

file_put_contents($filename, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the value of $text in each iteration as @zoubida13 said. As the counter increases, text value is changed to concatenation of elements corresponding to that counter. You can try the method provided by @zoubida13, or you can also use FILE_APPEND as third parameter inside file_put_contents and the code will go like this

`
$ticket = file_get_contents('php://input');
$ticket_output = json_decode($ticket,true);

$ticket_output_def = $ticket_output['ticket'];

$ticket_output_txt = print_r($ticket_output_def,true); 
$filename = "output.txt";

foreach ($ticket_output_def as $array) {

```
$array0 = $array[0];
$array1 = $array[1];
$text = $array0 . $array1;
file_put_contents($filename, $text,FILE_APPEND);
```

}

`

BUT, this will be an inefficient method I reckon, as it will try to write to the file each time. Its better to concat the text in each iteration and write it after the loop has executed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You have to use the PHP_EOL; Predefined Constant

```
$text = $text . $array0 . $array1 . PHP_EOL;
```